# Сортировка чисел введенных данных

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задание сделать сортировку введенных чисел по возрастанию.

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
w = int(input())
```

```
if x>y:
    q = x
    x = y
    y = q
if y>z:
    q = y
    y = z
    z = q
if x>y:
    q = x
    x = y
    y = q
if w>z:
    q = w
    w = y
    y = q
    z = x
    w = y
    x = z
    q = w
print(x)
print(y)
print(z)
print(w)
```

первые три `x` `y` `z` работают, но `w` - нет. подскажите пожалуйста.

**нужно именно через `>` сортировать, а не sort'ом.**

Answer (score 1):

Честная сортировка через `if`'ы:

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
w = int(input())

if x > y:
    x, y = y, x

if x > z:
    x, z = z, x

if x > w:
    x, w = w, x

if y > z:
    y, z = z, y

if y > w:
    y, w = w, y

if z > w:
    z, w = w, z

print(x)
print(y)
print(z)
print(w)
```

---

Тестирование алгоритма не выявило проблем:

```
import random

for _ in range(100000):
    arr = [random.randrange(1000) for _ in range(4)]
    x, y, z, w = arr

    if x > y:
        x, y = y, x

    if x > z:
        x, z = z, x

    if x > w:
        x, w = w, x

    if y > z:
        y, z = z, y

    if y > w:
        y, w = w, y

    if z > w:
        z, w = w, z

    arr_1 = [x, y, z, w]
    arr_2 = sorted(arr)
    assert arr_1 == arr_2, f"arr={arr}, arr_1={arr_1} vs arr_2={arr_2}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Без использования `sort`.

Представим, что переменные в списке, останется пройтись циклом и сравнить их:

```
def bubble_sort(arr):
    n = len(arr)

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n - i - 1):
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]:
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]

x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
w = int(input())

arr = [x, y, z, w]
bubble_sort(arr)

x, y, z, w = arr 
print(x)
print(y)
print(z)
print(w)
```